# How do I set local storage on a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, local-storage

The "modal-2" id opens a modal for a survey.

All I want is for this particular modal, to re-appear once every 24 hours after someone clicks the close button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var modals = ['#events'];
    if (window.location.hash && ~modals.indexOf(window.location.hash)) {
        $(window.location.hash).modal();
    }
    $("#modal-2").modal('show');
    $(".modal:not(.noclose)").on("click","a",function(){
        $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");
    });
});
```

Comment: What you can do is use a cookie that last 24hrs, check "if" the cookie is presence on refresh or new page load. "if not" call your modal `$('#myModal').modal({  show: true }). There is plenty of jquery Cookie plugins.

Not going to code it because i think it's a good exercise for you. :).

Comment: I'd like to keep the website cookie free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set current timestamp Date.now() to the localStorage and check it every time you need to decide whether to show the modal or not. Example code:

```
var twentyFourHoursInMs = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var lastTimestamp = Number(localStorage.getItem("last-showed-at"));
var currentTimestamp = Date.now();
if ((currentTimestamp - lastTimestamp) >= twentyFourHoursInMs) {
    localStorage.setItem("last-showed-at", currentTimestamp);
    $("#your-modal-id").modal("show");
    // Display modal once again
}
```

So this is the full code in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var modals = ['#events'];
    if (window.location.hash && ~modals.indexOf(window.location.hash)) {
        $(window.location.hash).modal();
    }

    $(".modal:not(.noclose)").on("click","a",function(){
        $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");
    });

    var currentTimestamp = Date.now();

    $("#cul8a").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        localStorage.setItem("last-showed-at", currentTimestamp);
    });

    // Check for modal eligibility

    var twentyFourHoursInMs = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var lastTimestamp = Number(localStorage.getItem("last-showed-at"));

    if ((currentTimestamp - lastTimestamp) >= twentyFourHoursInMs) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            localStorage.setItem("last-showed-at", currentTimestamp);
            $("#cul8a").modal("show");
        }, 4000);
    }
});
```

Comment: As I'm not familiar with jQ, should I replace my snippet with this one?

Comment: @Jim You need to replace in this code the `"#your-modal-id"` selector. As I understand, the modal that you do need to display is `"modal-2"`, so you do need to replace `"#your-modal-id"` to the `"#modal-2"`. You need to put this code to the place where you would like to check the re-appear eligibility, I guess it is in the `"$(".modal:not(.noclose)").on("click","a",function(){"` scope after the `.modal("hide");` line.

Comment: Correct! But it doesn;t work. Can you provide me the full code?

Comment: Thanx for providing the full code, appears to be slightly different from the one you provided before. However, has no effect. The modal re-appears.

Comment: @Jim This code will cause the modal to re-appear once in every 24 hours right after the modal close event, is this how you would like it to work?

Comment: Yes, that's all! But when I click the close button and refresh the browser it comes again. I want it to be available after 24 hrs. not before

Comment: @Jim Maybe do you want to cause re-appear **after 24-hours** (then again after 24hrs, and so on), not right after the close event (i.e. immediately, but once in 24hrs)?

Comment: In my experience is very annoying when visiting two or more times a day the website to keep always closing a modal that doesn't interest you at all.
By visiting https://jimmydance.com/indexa.html you'll see what is going wrong.

Comment: @Jim could you please re-check the answer - I did update the full code part, is it now doing what you do want?

Comment: It comes back all the time. I think the problem is the close button, probably it doesn't close programmatically.

Comment: @Jim I just checked the source code of the https://jimmydance.com/js/jsjs30.js on your site and it seems that it still uses the previous version of the full code, could you please update it to the latest version?

Comment: I did and now the navbar appears frozen

Comment: @Jim your https://jimmydance.com/js/jsjs30.js now have both new and old versions - you need to remove the old version (the second `$(document).ready(function() {`) in your file and it will work.

Comment: In the new js (jimmydance.com/js/jsjs31.js) there is only one, the new

Comment: @Jim this happens because you use some customized bootstrap modal in some unusual-incorrect way. As fix to that, you need to change (in HTML) the first line of the modal code to the `<div id="cul8a" class="modal1 fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cul8a" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none;">` (i.e. add the `style="display:none;"` to make it to do not overlap the whole page).

Comment: FINALLY!!!
Now I want to add a delay "$(window).ready(function(){setTimeout(function(){$("#cul8a").modal('show');}, 4000);});" where should I place this snippet?

Comment: @Jim I did update the code in the answer, take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109730/discussion-between-jim-and-exwei).